# Como agregar un elemento con php

Tags: php, html

Buen día me pregunto si se puede realizar la creación de elementos como `h1`, `h2`, `div` o botones en [html](/questions/tagged/html) desde [php](/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: Solo imprimir como una cadena los elementos `html` , por ejemplo `echo "<h1>contenido</h1> <h2>contenido</>h2"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes escribir cualquier etiqueta HTML usando la función `echo` de PHP, incluso crear tu web entera, hacer ciclos para creación de listas, etc. El resultado cuando consultes tupagina.com/pagina.php será todo el código HTML resultante.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
    echo "<p>Hola Mundo</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Añadir que además de las funciones de salida como `echo` o `print`, puedes hacer "roturas de código" para sacar html directamente.

```
<?php

    $var = 'foo';

    echo '<h1>Este texto concatena el valor de una variable ' . $foo . '</h1>';

    print "<h1>Este texto embebe el valor de una variable {$foo}</h1>";

    if ($var == 'foo') {
    ?>
    <h1>Esto es html</h1>
    <?php
    }
?>
```